# insert colon in the middle of 1300, C# String.format

Tags: c#, string

I need to learn how to use String.Format to insert colons in the middle of a 4 char strings, e.g. 1300 -> 13:00, or 0500 -> 05:00

Comment: something like string.Format("{0}:{1}", myString.SubString(0,2), myString.SubString(2,2)) ? You mean that? ie it's *always* going to be four char long?

Comment: Something like `string.format("{0}:{1}", s.Substring(0, 2), s.Substring(2))` ? But more important, did you try _anything_ to solve your problem?

Comment: @user2827377, are these time values ? like 1300, 1:00 PM ?

Comment: string.Format() is only there to concatain strings easily. That means you can only add the colon before or after 1300. Not in it. 
You can cut 1300 in 13 and 00 with string.Substring, then concatain the 3 strings with string.Format(), but the easiest and best way still is string.Insert()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`string.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var formattedString = yourString.Insert(2, ":");
```

Answer (score 2):

What about the String.Insert method 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
I hope that's help :)

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
string str = "0500";
string newstr = str.Insert(2, ":");
```

Answer (score 1):

if your string is always 4 characters length.

Try This:

```
string str = "1300";
string Formatted = str.Substring(0, 2) + ":" + str.Substring(2, 2);
```

Comment: Won't the `string.Insert` method be more efficient. In this example it doesn't matter. But if you would insert a character in a large string this method would do a large amount of useless copying.

Answer (score 1):

This code do the job:

```
string str = "1234";
str=str.Insert(2, ":");

 Console.Write(str);
```